# Is it possible to load data from different xml files into one Java class using XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

For instance I have two user accounts: a sender and recipient. Each of them has its own login and password to be used. And these fields are kept in xml config files like this:

```
<SenderData>
    <login>awesomeLogin</login>
    <password>awesomePass</password>
</SenderData>
```

In my tests I created Account class and I want to put there either sender or recipient data:

```
@XStreamAlias("SenderData")
public class Account {
    private String login, password;
}
```

I load required data from xml using `com.thoughtworks.xstream @XStream` and its alias, annotating the class with `@XStreamAlias("SenderData")` annotation.

It works perfectly for one specific xml source file, but if I have several xml sources (sender and recipient here) how can I load appropriate data using @XStream?
To be clear, my goal is to have two objects of one Account class, something like this:

```
Account sender = myXstream.load("SenderData", Account.class); //works!
Account recipient = myXstream.load("RecipientData", Account.class);//doesn't work
```

- the last will not work as I can put only one `@XStreamAlias("SenderData")` annotation to Account class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have to load thoses XML, and using xstream-distribution-1.4.9

1.first xml (recipient.xml)

```
<RecipientData>
    <login>naLogin</login>
    <password>anaPass</password>
</RecipientData>
```

2. second XML (sender.xml)

```
<SenderData>
    <login>awesomeLogin</login>
    <password>awesomePass</password>
</SenderData>
```

With this Account class :

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

@XStreamAlias("SenderData")
public class Account {
    private String login, password;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    /*public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }*/

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /*public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }*/


    public void toPtring(){
        System.out.println("login="+this.getLogin());
        System.out.println("pass="+this.getPassword());
    }
}
```

and test class :

```
public class maintest {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

        XStream xstream = new XStream(); 
        xstream.alias("SenderData", Account.class);
        FileReader r = new FileReader("sender.xml");
        Account sender=(Account)xstream.fromXML(r);     
        sender.toPtring();


        xstream.alias("RecipientData", Account.class);
        FileReader r2 = new FileReader("recipient.xml");
        Account recipient=(Account)xstream.fromXML(r2);
        recipient.toPtring();


    }
}
```

its works. like this result

```
login=awesomeLogin
pass=awesomePass
login=naLogin
pass=anaPass
```

Look at you code to see if you didn't forget something

Comment: I thought the class annotation `@XStreamAlias` is necessary to use. And didn't test different aliases like in your example. It works with your solution. Thank you very much!